# I am getting this error in android studio while running my app

Tags: java, android

ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'

I have been getting this error for a while now and its really bugging me. every time I hook up my phone and try to run my app, this error pops up.

I am new to android studio and I was doing my first ever project in it. I looked around a bit on the internet and found out to go to task manager and kill adb server but it did not help. If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I often run this batch file to get my ADB connection to work:

> rem  kill/start server
>
> Set ADBPath=D:\AndroidDevelopment\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\platform-tools\
>
> @REM set ADB_TRACE=1
>
> %ADBPath%adb devices
>
> %AdBPath%adb.exe kill-server
>
> %AdBPath%adb start-server
>
> MORE

Comment: how do i run this file? sorry i am new to this so. do i run this in a command line on windows?

Comment: This is the contents of a windows' batch file.  Create a file: kill_start.bat and put the above code in it.  It should execute when you click on it.